# Tests passing when run by ant but fail when run by maven?

Tags: ant, maven, surefire

Does anyone have any ideas why a test would pass when run with ant, but fail when run with maven?

I'm running my tests on windows and apparently there are some issues with surefire and windows? I've tried changing useSystemClassLoader=False and useManifestOnlyJar=true, but haven't been able to get them to work. The stack is below for the error I am getting when running the test with maven.

One thing I noticed is that there are $Proxy.someMethod calls in the stack, I have no idea where they are coming from.

Thanks for any help.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: cheetah.entities.businessdata.Attribute
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1153)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:678)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
        at $Proxy27.persist(Unknown Source)
        at cheetah.repositories.businessdata.jpa.JpaAttributeRepository.create(JpaAttributeRepository.java:28)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy29.create(Unknown Source)
        at cheetah.tests.integration.util.BusinessDataLookupData.createAttributeLookupData(BusinessDataLookupData.java:19)
        at cheetah.tests.integration.util.BusinessDataLookupData.create(BusinessDataLookupData.java:10)
        at cheetah.tests.integration.util.LookupData.create(LookupData.java:7)
        at cheetah.tests.integration.util.TestUtil.prepareData(TestUtil.java:23)
        at cheetah.repositories.businessdata.tests.integration.AttributeRepositoryTest.setUpClass(AttributeRepositoryTest.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:103)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:169)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: cheetah.entities.businessdata.Attribute
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:808)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:782)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:786)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:672)
        ... 43 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting forkMode=never in the sure fire configuration resolved the issue. I'm not sure of the reasoning, but without this option maven wasn't running pre-test code that ant was.

Answer (score 1):

The exception indicates an issue with a detached entity.
http://www.google.com.au/search?q=javax.persistence+detached+entity brings up a number of documents talking about detached entities.

From one of those documents - "Detached -- Detached entities have a persistent identity, but they are not currently actively managed within a persistence context."

From this I suspect that there is actually a problem with the code, rather than Ant or maven.

Comment: Hmm, I think you may be right. I just find it strange that the test passed in ant, but not in maven.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the ant build sets some sort of properties for the environment either via your ant script and properties files directly or via the ant task you are using and the Maven build does not do that.

That in turn leaves you with different test runtime configurations failing in Maven but not in Ant. Just a guess but I seen that before ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If it's related to 'pre test code' not being ran then maybe check out Maven failsafe plugin and look into the pre and post integration test phases of the lifecycle.

Also, Maven is quite possibly using a different classpath to Ant - referring to JARS in it's own local repo.  Something to watch out for.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the recommendation. I never realized that Surefire was only supposed to be used for unit testing and not integration testing - maybe that's why I was running into so many issues!